# Explicit example of an algebraic surface of Kodaira dimension 1 that is not a product of two curves.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, surfaces

I already know that the product of an elliptic curve and any curve of genus greater that 2 will give rise to a surface of Kodaira dimension 1.

Here is one strategy I have been suggested. Take a rational surface over the projective line that is a genus 1 fibration. For example the blow up of the base locus of a pencil of cubics. Then base change this to a curve of degree greater that 2 through a finite morphism. I am however unable to show that the resulting construction has Kodaira dimension 1 or that it is not the product of 2 curves.

Comment: To show it is has Kodaira dimension 1 one can use the canonical bundle formula: see e.g. Barth--Hulek--Peters--van de Ven Proposition V.12.5. (There should be a simpler argument but I don't see it at the moment.) Givn that, it is straightforward to show it is not a product of curves: the factors would have to have genus 1 and $\geq 2$ respectively, giving a different elliptic fibration $X \rightarrow C'$. But then a fibre of this fibration would be an elliptic curve which dominates the base curve $C$ of your original fibration, which is impossible.

Comment: The statement that I referred to in BHPvdV doesn't require you to know $\chi(O_X)$: it just says (in particular) that if the genus of the base is at least 2, then the Kodaira dimension is 1.

Comment: yes but in the proof of this statement they use that fact that the euler characteristic is greater than 0...and im not sure how to see this...

Comment: also how do we know that none of these elliptic curves are contained in fibers?

Comment: Which elliptic curves? And fibres of which morphism?

Comment: how do we know that the fibers of the morphism to C´arent contained in the fibers to C

Comment: If the fibres of the map to $C'$ are contained in the fibres of the map to $C$, then they are the same fibration. I would rather not use a chat room, and I don't want to keep writing new comments, but if you find what I said useful I am happy to write in an answer with a bit more detail. Otherwise I will leave it at this.

Comment: If you want to make this an answer with a bit more detail on the two points i have raised i would be happy to accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To repeat the setup of the question, let $f \colon S \rightarrow \mathbb P^1$ be a rational elliptic surface, let $g \colon C \rightarrow \mathbb P^1$ be a finite cover from a curve of genus at least 2, and let $\pi \colon X \rightarrow C$ be the base change of $f$ along $g$. So $\pi$ is an elliptic fibration with a nonempty set of singular fibres.

First we show that the Kodaira dimension of $X$ is $\kappa(X)=1$. Note that if $E$ is any smooth fibre of $\pi$, then adjunction gives that the restriction $(K_X)_{|E}$ is trivial. Since such curves $E$ cover a dense open set of $X$, this shows that $\kappa(X) \neq 2$. (Unfortunately, easy arguments like this don't seem sufficient to finish the proof.) On the other hand, by Iitaka's Conjecture $C_{2,1}$ (Barth--Peters--Hulek--van de Ven Theorem III.18.4) we have $\kappa(X) \geq \kappa(C) + \kappa(E) = 1$, so we conclude that $\kappa(X)=1$.

Now we show that $X$ is not a product of curves. Suppose $X=C_1 \times C_2$ where the $C_i$ are smooth curves. Then $\kappa(X) = \kappa(C_1)+\kappa(C_2)$. Since $\kappa(X)=1$ the only possibility is that one of the curves, $C_1$ say, is an elliptic curve. Considering any fibre $C_1 \times {p}$, the image $\pi(C_1 \times \{p\})$ must be a point, since $C_1$ can't dominate a curve of genus $\geq 2$ such as $C$. So every fibre of $X \rightarrow C_2$ is contained in a fibre of $\pi$. But this is impossible, for example because some of the fibres of $\pi$ are singular.

---

Footnote: the OP also asked in comments how to see that $\chi(O_X)$ is positive, as is required by the canonical bundle formula that I initially invoked in my proof. BHPvdV Proposition V.12.2 shows that $\chi(O_X) = \operatorname{deg}(\pi_* K_{X/C}))$, and the latter is non-negative by Theorem III.18.2 of op. cit. But the proof of this theorem is non-trivial and I can't really say any more about it than "read the book".

Comment: If the argument in my second paragraph is overkill and there is an elementary proof, I would be glad to learn it.

Comment: I guess $X \to C$ is a finite covering branched along a few fibers of $S \to \mathbb{P}^1$, so one can use the Riemann--Hurwitz formula to control $K_X$.

Comment: @Sasha: very good. Let me update when I get a chance...